# cannot find client_max_body_size of nginx.conf

Tags: file-upload, nginx, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having the old familiar problem

```
<html>
 <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
 <hr><center>nginx</center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I edited the `memory_limit`, `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` of php.ini.

But I cannot find the `nginx.conf` file anyware on my system and I dont know where to run those commands `# vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  I have Windows Server 2012 r2 and I am a newbie with nginx,  `conf` files and setting servers in general.

Thanks

**EDIT**

My system has windows 2012 server r2.  I did not installed nginx. Server (software/hardware) is new out of the box, has no other sites, only mine. Has only apache, nodejs, python, postgreSQL, geoserver and make 3.81. I have not installed anything else. Maybe my server connects with nginx from another server in the lan?

Comment: well `/etc` is a linux directory, you might want to check the `C:/` root or `program files`, how did you install nginx?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I just added more info to my original question. Maybe will help you spot the error.